# Testing value of csv field - Filter - Logstash

Tags: csv, if-statement, elasticsearch, filter, logstash

I need to set up a logstash conf file to export import csv file to elastic search.
My issue it's that I don't know how can I evaluate a csv field in a if statement.
I have a field "call_type" and I want to formated this like this:

```
 if ["call_type"] == "([a-z][A-Z][ ])*[dD]ata([a-z][A-Z][ ])*"
mutate 
{
 replace => ["call_type", "data" ]
}  }  else if ["call_type"] =~ "([a-z][A-Z][ ])*[vV]oix([a-z][A-Z][ ])*"
{
mutate 
{
replace => ["call_type", "voice" ]
}
}
else if ["call_type"] =~ "([a-z][A-Z][ ])*[sS]ms([a-z][A-Z][ ])*"
{
mutate
{
replace => ["call_type", "sms" ]
}  
}
```

"call_type" is unknow with this **if statement syntax**. 
Someone know **if statement syntax** ?

Comment: The if statement syntax is, of course, documented: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html#conditionals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your remarks.
I found my mistake. It comes from double quotes there : ["call_type"].

The good syntax to select the value from a csv field in a if statement is [call_type].

```
 if [call_type] =~ "([a-z][A-Z][ ])*[dD]ata([a-z][A-Z][ ])*"
{
mutate 
{
 replace => ["call_type", "data" ]
}  
}
else if [call_type] =~ "([a-z][A-Z][ ])*[vV]oix([a-z][A-Z][ ])*"
{
mutate 
{
  replace => ["call_type", "voice" ]
}
}
else if [call_type] =~ "([a-z][A-Z][ ])*[sS]ms([a-z][A-Z][ ])*"
{
mutate
{
  replace => ["call_type", "sms" ]
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet has a couple of typos. If with regex looks like this:

```
if ["call_type"] =~ "([a-z][A-Z][ ])*[sS]ms([a-z][A-Z][ ])*"
```

If you do:

```
if ["call_type"] == "([a-z][A-Z][ ])*[dD]ata([a-z][A-Z][ ])*"
```

you compare the string literal and not as regex.

You are missing the start quote on your first if.
If you fix these it should work supposing your regex is correct...